# Answer was apparently deleted for moderation purposes, but why?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I just failed yet [another audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9089502) which seemed ok to me, and after asking on [CV reviewers chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/24966113#24966113), it seems the answer may have been a pertinent one.

[image]

the link in the image goes [there](https://www.devart.com/odbc/sqlite/docs/index.html?using_odbc_driver.htm)

It seems clear, step by step and documented. It seems linked to the question.

**Why was this answer deleted?**

Comment: Perhaps as unsolicited advertisement i.e. spam. The links in the deleted answer are all to devart and David Fisher's other answers (on salesforce) are all pushing Skyvia, which is another devart product.

Comment: its really  hard to differentiate between this kind of spam and valid answer

Comment: I said this in chat but for completeness: The answer is almost a one-on-on copy of one the instruction pages of the linked site. If minitech noted that (or was flagged) it was deleted because of plagiarism. But that is hard to tell with only this post.

Comment: That user posted nothing but links to their blog all over the place. The post was deleted as spam, together with other posts.

Comment: Just never click "Looks ok" when the post was destroyed.  Easy peasy, stop and look.

Comment: That user posted nothing but links to their blog all over the place." ... "a "series of other posts by the same user" ... "Each answer was a basic copy of their blog post, intended to drive traffic to their blog."  How can it be plagiarism if the user is quoting himself ***and identifying/attributing the source?***

Comment: In the referenced answer, @Scott, the user does not identify his affiliation. It isn't plagiarism, it is shilling, monetizing Stack Overflow activity by using it as a traffic generator. "plagiarism" was the wrong word.

Comment: Why is using Stack Overflow as a traffic generator considered spam? If the answer is good, I'm really not seeing the problem.

Comment: @gilly3 The guidance for  [promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) or [self promotion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers) seem to be less relaxed about it...

Comment: I personally would welcome how-to tech bloggers, such as [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert), who regularly provide **good, relevant answers** that link back to their blog for more information. So, then, I may disagree with the community. But still, if the guidance is that "your post may be voted down", and not "self promotion is not allowed", why is this considered spam and deleted by moderators instead of just letting the community vote it down?

Comment: @gilly3 The main problem isn't linking to your blog/product, the problem is failing to disclose your affiliation with what you're linking to. It becomes a form of astroturfing. Further, if all or the majority of your contributions to the community serve to promote your own work, it raises questions about whether your efforts are intended to contribute to the community or abuse it to advance your own interests. Most of us are are here giving our help with no personal gain as members of this community. All of us *could* monetize that help, why should I give when the next guy is getting paid?

Comment: Most people who have and link to their blogs have no trouble disclosing their affiliation, and most of them organically contribute to the community in a fashion that leaves no question as to their motive. Eric Lippert is a great example. He regularly posts technical answers with great information, then occasionally *supplements* that with links to his blog where he has discussed the subject at hand. It is clear that his intention is to help, if that naturally entails a link to his blog, he adds it. He does not seek questions with the specific aim of posting a link to his own work.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The answer was deleted together with a series of other posts by the same user as spam.

Each answer was a basic copy of their blog post, intended to drive traffic to their blog.

As it is not a great audit post, I've twiddled with the post to remove it from automatic audit consideration.

Comment: exactly @MartijnPieters but how reviewer will know its plagiarism ? is it now work of reviewer to check for  plagiarism too ?

Comment: They are not; it is not a great audit post. I'll see if I can remove it from the audit pool.

Comment: I could have checked deeper. I noticed the answer was not present (not seeable by me) in the question, that could have hinted me. But well, it didn't.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier i dont think its intendant work for reviewer. So your action was legit :)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier unfortunately a lot of spam like this results in bad review audits.  The difference between a meh answer linking to an external site and spam is often that in the latter case the person will be posting the same thing in numerous places.  Once the initial ban-hammer comes down and all the spam is gone, that indicator vanishes with it.

Comment: Can posts deleted as part of a purge of one individual be not placed in the audit pool?

Comment: @TimB: that's not something we can easily detect; this post was manually deleted by a moderator as not *all* posts by that account needed deleting.

Comment: Many Admins are quick to react and slow to think... "Does deleting this post make Stack Overflow better?... or Worse?"

Comment: In this case, it definitely made stack overflow better. My experience in it is irrelevant @LeviFuller.