# Can this be removed from the audit list?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits, specific-answer

Full disclosure: I know nothing about the technologies involved in this answer.

I failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/9182398) at this location: (10k link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31619446/1768232)

> I had a similar problem for mocking POST requests. It is related to preflighted requests (see link below)
>
> [JQuery: Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/jquery-why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request)
>
> I added the Content-Type header to my request on the front-end, and that worked.

Yes, it does have a link, sure. But it also provides a recommendation for what to do, and even gives a little explanation. It's not the greatest answer, but it's not egregiously bad enough to be a review audit. Note also that the original [review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8922400) had 2 Looks OK in addition to the 6 Recommend Deletion.

Can it be undeleted, or at the very least can it be twiddled (upvote the deleted answer) to not go into the audit queue anymore?

Comment: It was [deleted from review](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31619446/revisions), with [2 LO and 6 RD votes](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8922400) (1 more LO vote, and it would *not* have been deleted at all). And here I thought review-audits should be unambiguous...

Comment: I would have voted to delete it.  It's a link to another SO post as an answer ("look at my answer here").  Those types of answers should be comments, not answers.

Comment: @JAL If you remove the first sentence and the link, it's a valid (though poor) answer. It's an answer.

Comment: @JAL So you are saying it's a duplicate-comment as an answer? I wonder why whoever flagged the answer didn't also flag the question then.

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It looks like this answer was undeleted by two 20ks and [Matt ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt), got some upvotes and downvotes, and then was deleted by [Flexo ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo).

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31619446/revisions

Since it has some upvotes now, it won't be in an audit anymore despite the fact that it has been re-deleted.

Comment: ... and now it's been downvoted and deleted again :(

Comment: Well, it was a rather bad answer, with not much in it except a link. And some genius made a radical edit to it so that some of the contents of the original answer disappeared. So the post has been deleted by 5 audits, went into the broken audit system to cause some havoc, got undeleted by diamond mod, possibly got vandalized, got downvoted, got deleted by diamond mod. And therefore it is now back in the audit system. If SO people could stop being "helpful" when there is no need for it, I think we would have ten times less problems. All of it shows that the SO moderation model is quite flawed.

Comment: Lets just limit that to the handling of this question being flawed - the only real negative outcome of that flawed handling here is that the question is yet again in the audit system where it can cause misery. Perhaps questions that have been reopened and closed should be disallowed from being audit questions, as that is a clear sign of dispute.

Comment: @Gimby It's not in the audit system. See my edit.

Comment: @durron597 are you sure? I was going off of what Lundin is saying.

Comment: @Gimby See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/301059/1768232); as far as I can tell he just undeleted it, upvoted it and redeleted it.

Comment: @durron597 I guess I'm misreading things then. It already doesn't help that I'm speaking of questions and this is actually about an answer. Withdrawn!